# TargetParameterCountException: C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**trying to invoke function through a string**

```
{
    object[] Parms = new object[] { "oiad", "abdj", "i" };
    Type thisType = GetType();
    MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("invo");
    ParameterInfo[] parameters = theMethod.GetParameters();

    if (parameters.Length != 0)
    {
      theMethod.Invoke(_instance, Parms);
    }
}

public void invo(object[] per)
{
    //
}
```

**Exception:**

```
TargetParameterCountException: Number of parameters specified does not match the expected number.
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.ConvertValues (System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] args, System.Reflection.ParameterInfo[] pinfo, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr) (at <7d97106330684add86d080ecf65bfe69>:0)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at <7d97106330684add86d080ecf65bfe69>:0)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters)
```

If I use `null` as parameter:

```
theMethod.Invoke(_instance, null);
```

it works fine. The problem is with passing parameter and `system.object`

Comment: null is ok with all.....(^_^)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I you write: `object[] Parms = new object[] { "oiad", "abdj", "i" };`

that means the args of  method invo are:    `public void invo(string s1, string s2, string s3)`

---

if  you have `public void invo(object[] per)`

you have to write `object[] Parms = new object[] { new object[]{ "oiad", "abdj", "i"}};`

Comment: Thank you...that makes more sense.